# R get the value from a column condition on the value in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am sorry for the title and format, I edited it several times, it looks OK in preview but  messy in the final version.

I tried to get the value from one column when the other column in 2 dataframes have same value.

I have two dataframes, df1 looks like
| Name |  ID   |  time | Month|
|------|-------|-------|------|
|A     |111    |2000   |3     |
|B     |222    |2001   |5     |
|B     |222    |2002   |7     |
|B     |222    |2003   |3     |
|C     |333    |2002   |9     |
|C     |333    |2005   |4     |

df2 looks like
|Name   |time|
|-------|----|
|A      |2007|
|B      |2002|
|C      |2000|

after "rbind.fill" them  get

| Name | ID | time | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 111 | 2000 | 3 |
| B | 222 | 2001 | 5 |
| B | 222 | 2002 | 7 |
| B | 222 | 2003 | 3 |
| C | 333 | 2002 | 9 |
| C | 333 | 2005 | 4 |
| A | NA | 2007 | NA |
| B | NA | 2002 | NA |
| C | NA | 2000 | NA |

But I actually want the column ID also be filled ,like this:
|Name  |ID    |time   |Month|
|------|------|-------|-----|
|A     |111   |2000   |3    |
|B     |222   |2001   |5    |
|B     |222   |2002   |7    |
|B     |222   |2003   |3    |
|C     |333   |2002   |9    |
|C     |333   |2005   |4    |
|A     |***111***  |2007    |NA|
|B     |***222***  |2002    |NA|
|C     |***333***  |2000    |NA|

I want the **ID column** to be filled when the Name in 2 dataframes are the same.

I tried "ifelse"  "mapvalues" etc,did not work
'longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length' is also there when I use "ifelse", since 2 dataframes have different number of rows

Could somebody provide a elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use match, which gets the first match.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  bind_rows(df2) |> 
  mutate(ID = ID[match(Name, Name)])
```

```
Name  ID time Month
1    A 111 2000     3
2    B 222 2001     5
3    B 222 2002     7
4    B 222 2003     3
5    C 333 2002     9
6    C 333 2005     4
7    A 111 2007    NA
8    B 222 2002    NA
9    C 333 2000    NA
```